# Writing a raster file from multi-dimension array using Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, numpy

I've been attempting to create a raster file that has multiple bands (10 or more) from a numpy array with multiple dimension(i.e. 10 or more). The script I'm currently using exports the TIFF file I want to produce but the file turns out to be black (blank) image.

The shape of the data has a dimension of (1120,872,12) (rows, cols, bands) and I wanted to create a raster file that has 12 bands.

```
input_array.shape
 (1120, 872, 12)
```

---

```
def CreateTiff(output, array, driver, noData, GeoT, Proj, DataType):

    rows = array.shape[0]
    cols = array.shape[1]
    band = array.shape[2]

    array[np.isnan(array)] = noData
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')

    DataSet = driver.Create(output, rows, cols, band, gdal.GDT_Float32)
    DataSet.SetGeoTransform(GeoT)
    DataSet.SetProjection(Proj)

    for i, image in range(array.shape[2], 1):
        DataSet.GetRasterBand(i).WriteArray(image)
        DataSet.GetRasterBand(i).SetNoDataValue(NoData)
    DataSet.FlushCache()
    return Name
```

with this function,

```
# the raster output layer

output_file = r'rasterfile.tiff'

# Writes raster

CreateTiff(output_file, input_array, driver, noData, GeoTransform, Projection, DataType)
```

As I mentioned above, this function creates the raster file I was hoping to get but when I inspect it in QGIS, the file is a black(blank) image and the values are zeros.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your range loop is empty:

```
list(range(array.shape[2], 1)
[]
```

Try:

```
for i in range(band):
    DataSet.GetRasterBand(i+1).WriteArray(array[:, :, i])
    DataSet.GetRasterBand(i+1).SetNoDataValue(NoData)
```

Comment: hey @Luke,  thanks for point out the issue with the range loop I used. when I used your suggestion, this error returns: 
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'WriteArray'`

Comment: @Destaneon  i'm facing similar problem of saving ndarray as raster with many bands, I have tried your function but i'm not sure what is the parameter "DataType" , could you maybe elaborate what should be this parameter? :) thanks

Comment: @Reut the DataType in Destaneon's is probably supposed to be one of the `gdal.GDT_*` data type constants, but the function doesn't actually use this argument, `gdal.GDT_Float32` is hardcoded instead.